# AS3 : XML Into Array Login Form Details

Tags: xml, arrays, forms, actionscript-3, authentication

I want to make a login form in as3. I have two input text fields (username, password) and one submit button on stage. When user inputs those fields and hit submit I want the flash to load the all available usernames and password into an array and check if the input details match to any of the imported details of XML into array. If it matches it traces welcome otherwise invalid input.

How to do it?

What I have tried so far: two text fields with instance name : txt_usr, txt_pass.

Comment: please post some code with expected output and what you get...

Comment: Recommending closure here, it's old and abandoned, and doesn't feature any meaningful research.

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var xml:XML =
<users>
    <user name='Alex' pass='123' />
    <user name='Ford' pass='567' />
</users>

btnSubmit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, DataChecking);

function DataChecking(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    for (var i:int = 0; i <= xml.user.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i < xml.user.length()) {
            if (xml.user[i].@name == txt_user.text && xml.user[i].@pass == txt_pass.text)
            {
                //authorized user
                trace('authorized user');
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //user not found
            trace('user not found');
        }
    }
}
```

If not an option, then you need more information